# Вычисляемые поля в литеральной записи XElement

Tags: xml, vb.net

Возможно ли в следующем коде вместо строк `Id` и `Value` подставить в возвращаемый объект передаваемые в функцию значения?

```vb
Function DoIt(Id As String, Value As String) As XElement
  Return <smth id="Id">
           <value>Value</value>
         </smth>
End Function
```

Я понимаю, что можно сделать так:

```vb
Public Function DoIt(Id As String, Value As String) As XElement
  Dim Res = <smth>
              <value></value>
            </smth>

  Res.SetAttributeValue("id", Id)
  Res.Descendants("value")(0).Value = Value

  Return Res
End Function
```

но хотелось бы именно в литеральную форму упихать.

PS: И нет, это не сериализация. Мне для другого надо. Хотя там оно тоже не сильно к месту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы не использовать обычный вызов конструктора?

```
Return New XElement("smth", new XAttribute("id", Id), new XElement("value", Value))
```

Если нужен именно литерал - то синтаксис описывается в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384964.aspx):

```
  Return <smth id=<%=Id%>>
           <value><%=Value%></value>
         </smth>
```

Но как по мне, так этот синтаксис просто ужасен.